# Custom Servlets Configuration in Liferay

Tags: jsp, servlets, liferay

I have some legacy applications built with JSP and Servlets on tomcat . This application has form action which call Servlets for processing. It has to be deployed under Liferay application.

JSP can be easily deployed under ROOT directory but facing issue with "Servlets" configuration.

Approach:

1) Copy class files under \webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes
2) Configure Servlets mapping under \webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\web.xml

After changing these setting unable to start Liferay. I want some quick fix for this issue.

Comment: to get an even quicker fix for your problem, why don't you include some more information than "unable to start"? E.g. what did you try, what error message do you see? And why are you adding your legacy application to Liferay - which does a whole lot of initialization and might not be happy with all the jars your application brings with it. You're supposed to install other applications next to Liferay, as a separate web application. IMHO it's not worth going the route that you describe.

Comment: Please provide me any reference link to deploy application next to liferay. This application URL should come under same domain that is used by liferay installation.

Comment: why don't you include some more information than "unable to start"? Asking for a reference to documentation is a reason to close your question on stackoverflow - read bulletpoint 4: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic